# Error (RangeError (index): Invalid value: Valid value range is empty: 0)

Tags: flutter, range

I ran the below code but i keep getting errors, how can i resolve this?

```
Expanded(
            child: ListView.builder(
              itemCount: 4,
              scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
              itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                Shoe shoe = value.getShoeList()[index];
                return ShoeTile(
                  shoe: shoe,
                  onTap: () => addShoeToCart(shoe),
                );
```

[image]

I used the list view and was expecting to get a list moving in a horizontal axis.

Comment: put list.length in item count property.

Comment: Please instead of link paste the image and provide more code.

Answer (score 2):

Set

```
ListView.builder( itemCount:value.getShoeList().length ,
```

You are giving fix 4 count to list view but it seems to be your array is greater than 4 so that you are getting this error.